# C++ separation data and logic

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, dependencies, dependency-management

The reason why I want to separate in such way - data depends from nothing, methods can have hundred dependencies. All, who depends from data shouldn`t depends from methods dependencies.

I want to do something like:

```
//s_class_name.h
struct structName
{
    data m_data
}
```

---

```
//class_name.h
class className : public structName
{
public:
    void method(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argN); //using m_data
}
```

---

```
static_cast<className *>(&structNameObject)->method(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argN);
```

There are I see two problems:

1) All acces to data is opened. I want to open data to all, who operate with struct, but not with class.

2) Static cast downcasting is undefined.

Could you explain me, how to realize pattern data&logic separation better?

UPD.: I have another idea, but I cant explain why it`s bad:

1) In s_class_name.h, I can declare template methods
2) In class_name.h, I can instante template args.

Comment: Dieter Lücking, I am sorry. Fixed

Comment: *"I want to open data to all, who operate with struct, but not with class."* Do you mean that you want to open data to all the classes who operate on the data, and you want the data to be hidden to the users of the classes ?

Comment: My point of view: Logic or behavior can not be expressed (sanely) with objects.

Comment: I mean, that I want to open fileds of the struct to all who operate with this struct. But i want to hide it from all, who operate with the class.

Answer (score 1):

## Possible implementation of your design:

One way to avoid use of the data form unauthorized access is to make the data protected:  only classes inheriting from your data structure will be able to access it:

```
 class structName
 {
 protected:  // only classes inheriting from this structure can access the data
    data m_data;
 };
```

Then the classes inheriting from the data structure can use data as needed:

```
class className : public structName
{
public:
    void method(int arg1) { //using m_data
        for (int i = 0; i < arg1; i++)
            cout << i << ":" << m_data << endl; 
    }
};
```

And you can do things like:

```
className c;    // if your object was a class before 
structName*d=&c; 
static_cast<className *>(d)->method(10);  // you can downcast
               // if your object wasn't a class before, it's UB, but it could probably work if your class has not virtuals and no own data.
```

## Weakness of this design:

1) The separation of data from logic does not allow for object encapsulation.

2) The initialisation of data must be done by the derived class.  This means that you'll have to take care of systematic explicit initialisation, because there's no other way to ensure consistency of your data.

3) You can link a class to the wrong data structure.

4) Once a class inherits from the data structure, any other class can inherit from the class, puting an end to the design.

5) Your fundamental assumption that data doesn't depend on anything might prove to be wrong.  The methods that you offer, might need private data (for example to hold subtotals, and other denormlized redundant data that you may keep for performance purpose for example) that is tightly linked with the data.  Hence the data depends also on the methods you implement.

6) Your structure is not able to implement properly polymorphism and inheritance:  if you have a data struture `dStructName` inheriting from `StructName`, then you'd need as well a `dclassName` derived from `className`.  But `dclassName` would already inherit from `StructName` ... So it'll be a very delicate issue to solve, while with traditional object oriented design (encapsulating data+methods into meaningful objects) it's a piece of cake.

## Improved design:

An improved way is to use composition, bcause you can't really say that `className` **is a** `structName`, but you could well pretend that `className` **has a** `structName`.

Then the design looks a little bit like a proxy pattern which *provides a surrogate for another object to control access to it* (GoF), or a decorator, depending how you see it.

```
struct structName { data m_data; };

class className {
private: 
    structName *data;   // access to your data object 
public:
    className(structName *d) : data(d) {}  // constructor 
    void method(int arg1) { //using m_data
            cout << data->m_data << endl; 
    }
};
```

Here are some possible uses:

```
structName d; 
className cn(&d);        // creating an object 
cn.method(10);           // using methods on the data 
className(&d).method(3); // throw away temporary object destroyed when expression is evaluated. 
                         // so no need for down-casting anymore.
```

With this design, weaknesses 1, 4, and 6 disapear.  This approach would be ideal, for example if your struct data is uploaded form a database on demand.

Comment: "I mean, that I want to open fileds of the struct to all who operate with this struct. But I want to hide it from all, who operate with the class."

Comment: And I cant make downcast  because, formally, it is UB

Comment: If you want to hide it from all who operate on the class, you should go to private inheritance.  But then no downcasting anymore.  The other way would be to use composition rather than inheritance (according to the principle that `className` **is** not really **a** `structName`, but in reality **has-a** `structName`)

Comment: @pvl I added a section with a suggestion for an improved design using composition.

Comment: Thx! But I strictly don't understand - class object is data, so `structNameObject` and `classNameObject` is objects of same type. Why there are no trivial conversion(why there are no equivalence relation(not inhertance) between "data clases" and "function clases")?

Comment: About weakness:  
1) I think worse way to make "details depends from details". Struct fields is details and method args is details, methods are converters. 
2) I`ve lied. I want to separate all methods which depends from "other"(not inside-structure) data.  
3) See 2.  
4) What for somebody will inherits from controller/converter class and why it weakness? 
5) See 1.  
6) Why? All derived from structName can be converted to className. But now there are just no correct instrument for this.

Comment: *I want to separate all methods which depends from "other"(not inside-structure) data.* sounds much more reasonable. However it's difficult to give a good answer when having broad questions and not all the cards in hand.  I suggest that you post a more concrete question showing what you really intend to do in a more tangible manner.